# Exporting an Eclipse plugin with a dependency on an external jar

Tags: eclipse, plugins, jar, dependencies, export

Just recently started using Eclipse and ran into an issue with exporting the plugin I'm working on. I tried to search but so far no luck - but if the answer is already here I'd be grateful if someone can point me to it.

I'm writing a n OSGi/Equinox plugin with Eclipse. The plugin is for a 3rd party system, which allows extensions: basically all jars placed in the application's plugin folder are automatically loaded into the application at startup. I have managed to put together my plugin, it's loading fine and it works.
The issue is that I rely on another plugin which is placed beside mine in the plugins folder. For obvious reasons I do not want to package that plugin into my plugin jar file. I have tried to add the dependency as an external archive, but this breaks the export: when I try to export my plugin project ant complains about missing dependencies and types. (If I actually include the other jar file in my plugin everything works, but obviously this is less then ideal.)

So: how do I set up my plugin project dependency, that it's a) an external dependency and b) doesn't need to be specified with a path or a variable - i.e. how do I tell my exporter to "don't worry, it will be there right beside you"?

Edit: Apparently there's an important detail I didn't mention. The external jar file I depend on is **not** an OSGi plugin, just a regular jar file with some classes in it. To the 3rd party system it seems all the same (all are under the plugins folder, all are loaded into the application), but for Eclipse the distinction seems important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end the solution to my specific problem was to add the external jar file as an Extra Classpath Entry on the build properties tab (this translated to a "jars.extra.classpath = .jar" entry in the build.properties file). I have also added the jar file to the project itself - after adding the extra class path entry that got changed into an external dependency automatically.

With these two changes I was able to successfully export my plugin, which didn't contain the external jar file, but was able to reference it when loaded into the 3rd party system.

Answer (score 2):

If you reference the other plug-in as a dependency in your plug-in's MANIFEST.MF the export should work without errors. The plug-in should be listed in the `Require-Bundle` list in the MANIFEST.MF.

You can do this in the MANIFEST.MF editor by adding to the 'Required Plug-ins' list on the 'Dependencies' tab of the editor.

Note: When referencing other plug-ins you must always use this method. Do not try adding the plug-in jar to the Java build path or anything like that.

If the jar you want to use is not an Eclipse plug-in you must should include it as part of the plug-in and list the jar in the `Bundle-Classpath` in the MANIFEST.MF. If you cannot do this you can reference an external jar in the `Bundle-Classpath` using something like:

```
Bundle-Classpath: .,external:$LIB_LOCATION$/lib.jar
```

`.` is the normal entry in for the plug-in code. `external:$LIB_LOCATION$/lib.jar` looks for `lib.jar` in a location defined by the environment variable `LIB_LOCATION`. This method can be difficult to get right.

Comment: Unfortunately it seems that the Required Plug-ins list only accepts plugin-type jars - while my external jar is a regular jar file with some classes in it (see my edit above). Any further suggestions?

Comment: I've tried what you suggested. I have to add my extra jar as an external jar dependency at least to make it build. Then I added external:<mylib>.jar to the Bundle-Classpath as suggested, but the export still fails unfortunately. The error says:
<workspace>/<myplugin>/<mylib>.jar = src does not exist!